# how do I allow a VBA search to not look for only exact matches

Tags: vba, if-statement, wildcard

I have this code,

`If ((dataArray(i, *searchField*) = *searchValue*)  Then`

Which is not working. what I am trying to achieve is;

if all of search value is in any part of search field or vice versa then do X

Any help?

Comment: The '\*xxxxxx*' syntax isn't valid VBA.  You are likely to get more help if you provide more code and explain more clearly what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

use the **Like** verb

```
if dataArray(i) Like searchValue
```

where search value begins and ends with astricks
it is a string compairson